# Select a row from two tables depend on primary key(Mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two table users and album. In users table there is `user_id` primary key .In other table albums there are multiple rows with that `user_id` because every time when a user upload a new album it uploads with `user_id` as foreign key. I want to select only once the `user_id` with other table(album) ignore other result set.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what are the columns in your table album that indicates the sequence of record? is there a date when the album was uploaded?

Comment: what are the columns in your album table?

Comment: i want foreign key appers only once in the result set with all other columns

Comment: yep, i know. but there can be multiple rows in the table album for every `user_ID` right?

Comment: These are the fields in album table  album_id  user_id  title  title_url  composer  description  photo_id  search

Comment: see my answer below if it works.. need some feedback.

Comment: yes,there are multiple rows with user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN album b
            ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_ID, MAX(photo_id) max_rec
            FROM album
            GROUP BY    user_ID
        ) c ON b.user_ID = c.user_ID AND
                b.photo_id = c.max_rec
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT album.* FROM album LEFT JOIN users ON user.id = album.id WHERE user.id = SOMEIDHERE
```

I believe this will work, your not giving me a whole lot of info to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT u.*, a.*
        FROM users AS u
        INNER JOIN album AS a
        ON u.user_ID = a.user_ID
        ORDER BY a.created DESC) AS h
GROUP BY user_ID
```

`ORDER BY b.created DESC` -> `ORDER BY` whatever row you wish for. In this case the newest one is chosen.